# How to solve zookeeper.properties file is missing error

Tags: apache-kafka, config, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to start a `Zookeper` instance and i keep getting an error that says the `zookeeper.properties` file does not exist..when in fact it does.

> $ ./script.sh [2019-06-30 07:40:00,844] INFO Reading configuration
>   from: .\config\zookepeer.properties
>   (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig) [2019-06-30
>   07:40:00,844] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally
>   (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
>   org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException:
>   Error processing ./config/zookepeer.properties
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:156)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:104)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:81)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   .\config\zookepeer.properties file is missing
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:140)
>           ... 2 more Invalid config, exiting abnormally

**Folder structure**

```
-root
   -config
      -zookeeper.properties
   -bin
      -zookeeper-server-start.sh
   -script.sh
```

**Script**

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookepeer.properties
```

**Zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the properties file name in script.

./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/**zookepeer.properties** . 
Change it as,

```
./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ./config/zookeeper.properties
```

and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
./zookeeper-server-start.sh ../config/zookeeper.properties
```

Whereby you are located in the **bin** directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd in D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows> and run

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Open another cmd  in D:\Learning\kafka\kafka_2.13-3.5.0\bin\windows> and run

```
kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
```